# How to create the paragraph (in label) with Read More/Read Less at the end?

Tags: iphone, swift3

I would like to create the paragraph(in label) with Read More/Read Less at the end. I am beginner in iPhone Application development.

**this my code...**
**i am getting an error  in else condition That error is "Value of type NSLayoutConstraint" has no member 'font'" at lbl.contant = getheight....**

```
@IBOutlet weak var lbl: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!        

var isLabelAtMaxHeight = false

@IBAction func ButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if isLabelAtMaxHeight {
        btn.setTitle("Read more", for: .normal)
        isLabelAtMaxHeight = false
        lbl.constant = 70
    }
    else {
        btn.setTitle("Read less", for: .normal)
        isLabelAtMaxHeight = true
        lbl.constant = getHeightOfLabel(text:"Isn't it? How to do? I'm sorry I don't know how to solve this exactly. :( – May Phyu Feb 20 at 11:16 No, i dont mean like that. When you set text to label then U have to find height of label then assign that height to label with setting property number of lines = 0 – Jitendra Modi Feb 20 at 11:31" , width:
            view.bounds.width, font: lbl.font)
    }
}



func getHeightOfLabel(text: String, width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat
{
    let lbl = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    lbl.frame.size.width = width
    lbl.font = font
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0
    lbl.text = text
    lbl.sizeToFit()
    return lbl.frame.size.height
}
```

Comment: This is far too broad and unresearched for a Stack Overflow question, unfortunately. Would you edit it to show what you have tried, and what specific problem you are having?

Comment: @Shaik.Sahilpasha font : lbl.font is your mistake . Give your label name here

Comment: lbl is label name ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create an outlet for height constraint of your paragraphLabel.
- Set top layout of your "Read more" button to paragraphLabel.
- On clicking "Read more" button increase height constraint constant, on clicking "Read less" decrease height constraint constant.

  ```
  @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var yourParagraphLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var lblHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

  var isLabelAtMaxHeight = false

  @IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: Any) {
      if isLabelAtMaxHeight {
      btn.setTitle("Read more", for: .normal)
      isLabelAtMaxHeight = false
      lblHeight.constant = 70
  }
  else {
     btn.setTitle("Read less", for: .normal)
     isLabelAtMaxHeight = true
     lblHeight.constant = getHeightOfLabel(text: yourParagraphText, width: 
     view.bounds.width, font: yourParagraphLabel.font)
  }
  }
  ```

  Get height of a text

  ```
  func getHeightOfLabel(text: String, width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat 
  {
     let lbl = UILabel(frame: .zero)
     lbl.frame.size.width = width
     lbl.font = font
     lbl.numberOfLines = 0
     lbl.text = text
     lbl.sizeToFit()
     return lbl.frame.size.height
  }
  ```

Comment: once check it out my code i am getting an error in  ButtonAction else condition....

Comment: Can you explain more about your code ? which one is your paragraph label IBoutlet and which one you have taken heightConstraint IBoutlet

Comment: i think you have not declared IBOutlet UILabel. You have only declared label height constraint.

Comment: yup i declared only label height constraint ...i haven't declared IBOutlet..  **is it possible to declare  label height constraint and IBOutlet at the same label** ..

Comment: ok ....And in else condition how we can take   **yourparagraphText.....**  i have to define in viewdidload are how we can define...